# Discontinuous vertical line in table in booktabs

Tags: tables, booktabs

I have the following table. How can I

1- have a continuous vertical line (rather than the discontinuous current one)

2- make the vertical line similar in size to the last bottom horizontal line (i.e. thick)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

 \usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tbl:data} 
\begin{tabular}{c|ccccc} \toprule 
    Method           & y_1 & y_2 &y_3  & y_4 & y_5 \\ \midrule
    x_1 &  &   &  &   & \\ \midrule
    x_2 &  &   &  &   & \\ \midrule
    x_3 &  &   &  &   &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is by design. In general the `booktabs` rules should not be used in combination with vertical lines. Often these lines makes the data harder to read so it is better to nbot use any vertical lines at all.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Since you load `tabularray` package, I would use in writing your table. It remove gaps in vertical lines at use of `booktabs` rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Caption}
\label{tbl:stages}
    \begin{tblr}{hline{3-Y}={solid}, $ <---
                 vline{2}={\heavyrulewidth},
                 colspec={Q[c, mode=math] ccccc},
                 row{1} = {mode=math}
                 }
    \toprule
\text{Method}  
        & y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 & y_5   \\ 
    \midrule
x_1     &     &     &    &     &        \\
x_2     &     &     &    &     &        \\
x_3     &     &     &    &     &        \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

According to my opinion, I would remove horizontal lines in table body, to get more "professional" look of it:

[image]

For this table in above MWE remove code line `hline{3-Y}={solid}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like the last table!

Comment: @Rudinberry, you are welcome. Since the contents of cells in table body is unknown, I left your selection c for column types. However, if in cells are decimal numbers, you may consider to use `siunitx` package loaded as `tabularray` library (similarly as are `amsmath` and `booktabs`), which enable align decimal numbers at their decimal points.